# Why dereference specific address in Visual Studio sometime not lead to access violation errors?

Tags: c, dereference

```
int* p =(int*) 0x00030080;
*p = 255;
```

leads to *access violation error*.

But this

```
int* p =(int*) 0x00020080;
*p = 255;
```

does not.

I understand that they are all virtual memories in RAM so I think maybe I can have right to access `0x00020080` at this time but it maybe not another time (another executions in my PC or in other PCs).

But the result is that I can always access to `0x00020080`.

Could you tell me the reason or at least an exist answer in Stackoverflow (which I still not find out) ?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

**Edit**: Because some of you said it was just a lucky, I have sent this piece of code for all my team (more than 20 computers) and all of them can access to `0x00020080` without error. So is this lucky or `0x00020080` is one (of some) fixed memory addresses that we can access through Visual Studio ?

Comment: I guess because you happened to hit memory that you have access to?

Answer (score 2):

Your process has a virtual memory space. Some addresses are mapped to physical memory and some are not.  It can appear to work if physical memory is mapped into that location, and it doesn't work if it is not. But if you don't know what is at that address, writing to it could very likely corrupt your program.

Comment: but why, like I said, I can always access to `0x00020080`

Comment: No, it is not undefined behavior at all. The code is perfectly fine as far as C is concerned. The C language mentions nothing about virtual vs physical memory addressing. That is something which is beyond the scope of a programming language standard.

Comment: @Codino In whatever process you are running, your OS always maps something (code, data, stack, heap, etc.) to that address. What that is you don't know so you shouldn't change it.  There are ways to find out. Compilers usually have some switch to generate address maps of compiled code.

Comment: @Lundin, ok, implementation defined.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Not that either. Undefined and impl.-defined behavior are C language terms, implying that this is something in scope of the C standard. But C simply does not specify how an ABI maps memory, because that's not related to the C language.

Comment: @Lundin, I understand that, but I am not quoting the C language spec.  It may be legal C, but it is still a bad idea to write to unknown addresses and the results vary by OS and compiler implementation.  So while the C spec has a specific definition of "implemention defined", it is still defined by *an* implementation :)  I took out the terms in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

"Access violation error" is what happens when you access a spot in process virtual address space that has not been "allocated" yet from the OS's point of view. The OS and the underlying hardware knows that this area in address space is free/empty and therefore illegal to access. OS-level and hardware-level memory protection mechanisms will immediately trigger the error if you attempt to access such points in the virtual address space.

If some region of address space has already been requested from the OS ("allocated"), the OS effectively hands all control over that region to the process and relieves itself from any responsibilities for that region. That memory belongs to the process. The process can do anything with that region of address space - it will not trigger any OS-level memory protection mechanisms.

In your case the address `0x00020080` just accidentally happened to fall into some already allocated region of address space owned by your process, which is why you can access it successfully. Meanwhile, `0x00030080` falls into an unallocated region, protected by OS.

P.S. The OS typically offers slightly finer control over what you can do with virtual memory region. A region might be already allocated, yet labeled as "read-only". In this case OS-level memory protection mechanisms will allow read-access to that region, but prevent write-access. In your case there's a possibility of `0x00030080` falling into an already allocated read-only region. In that case it is your attempt to *write* into it that triggers the error.

Comment: @Codino: Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including appearing to work until the day you ship. Your program's memory layout is probably deterministic enough to make this not crash, for now. There's really nothing more to wonder, this answer covers it all. Your address happens to work. It probably won't always work. Don't do this.

Comment: I don't think it is Undefined Behavior. Cannot find out a document mention this case is UB.

Comment: @Codino: I don't see how your update changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Because you were lucky. Not only you managed to pick a virtual memory address that has some memory block attached to it, but you also happen upon a memory with a write access. Origin of this memory is largely depending on your application. It could be a process or private heap block, `.data` section of executable/dll, memory mapped file, or anything else. Successful writing for that memory address could also have some sort of "persistence", because on your machine your OS always loading some module/allocating some heap memory at the same address. It will most likely be broken on some other system with different OS version or memory configuration.

Also it is worth pointing out, that writing random memory address is an undefined behavior, so technically anything could happen and it is pointless to expect some behavior patterns from it.

Comment: No, it is not undefined behavior at all. The code is perfectly fine as far as C is concerned. The C language mentions nothing about virtual vs physical memory addressing. That is something which is beyond the scope of a programming language standard.